# Rails 2.3.8 routing equivalent of Rails 3 match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise, ruby-on-rails-2

What is the equivalent of `match 'aliased/route/here' => 'pointed/route/here'`?

I'm banging my head on the wall here, because I can't get Devise to work with different login url's for the same model. If anyone has tips regarding this issue, I appreciate it!

The current version of my routes looks like this:

```
auth.devise_for :somerole,    :class_name => 'MainRole', :as => 'niceurl'
auth.devise_for :anotherrole, :class_name => 'MainRole', :as => 'otherurl'
```

But the `:class_name` option does not all the work: I'm still required to create all the appropiate helpers for every role I define.

I am currently using Devise 1.x in a Rails 2.3.8 environment, so that's why the solution offered on Github and mentioned on other questions won't work.

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Okay, so I found a workaround for Devise to work: I created a method in my `application_controller` that collects all my different roles and assigns it to the mainrole like so:

```
def current_mainrole
  current_somerole || current_anotherrole
end
```

I'm afraid it might introduce some securityleaks and it really looks like a hack, so I'm hoping still someone can help me out with the routing issue.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent in 2.3.8 is

```
map.contact '/contact', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'contact'
```

So you can tailor the line to your needs.

Take a look at these links for further reading:
[Ruby on Rails Tutorial 2.3](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout?version=2.3#sec%3arails_routes)
[Ruby on Rails Guides 2.3.8](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/getting_started.html#adding-a-route)

Hope I helped.

Comment: I'm familiar with named routes, but with the use of Devise it is a bit more complicated than just pointing to a controller and action, unfortunately. Devise also takes the url you are using into account for naming helpers and stuff, so I really want to point one url to another.

Comment: My appologies. The little I played with devise was with Rails 3, and I decided to write my own. It was a bad assumption on my part...